# Copying all XML elements and updating one of them in XSL

Tags: xslt

I have a requirement in my project some thing like this, 
I have to copy all the elements from an xml  and for few elements I have to update if present else I have to add it.

For example in the below xml I have an element Extrensic name "taxIncluded"> , in translated xml I want the value of it be updated.If it is missing I have to include it.

**input xml 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InvoiceHeader>
    <Item1>
    Item description
    </Item1>

    <Extrensic name="taxIncluded">
        <percentage>
     10%
        </percentage>
    </Extrensic>
</InvoiceHeader>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InvoiceHeader>
    <Item1>
    Item description
    </Item1>

    <Extrensic name="taxIncluded">
        <percentage>
     20%
        </percentage>
    </Extrensic>
</InvoiceHeader>
```

**input xml 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InvoiceHeader>
    <Item1>
    Item description
    </Item1>
</InvoiceHeader>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InvoiceHeader>
    <Item1>
    Item description
    </Item1>

    <Extrensic name="taxIncluded">
        <percentage>
     20%
        </percentage>
    </Extrensic>
</InvoiceHeader>
```

I tried creating xsl but it is not working as expected, I thought of including it here but it is a very big xsl, in the above xml example I added only a part of it.

Could some one please help me how to do it?

Comment: Yes, you were right not to include a "very big xsl", but we still need to see XSLT code. Please simplify your code and post a minimal sample, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mathias, Just now only I saw your comment as I was busy with some escalations in my team. I got the working xsl in this thread.Thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it with XSLT 2.0 ...

### Method 1:

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:param name="taxIncluded" select="20" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="InvoiceHeader[not( Extrensic[@name='taxIncluded'])]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    <Extrensic name="taxIncluded">
        <percentage>
          <xsl:value-of select="$taxIncluded" />%
        </percentage>
    </Extrensic>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Extrensic[@name='taxIncluded']/percentage">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:value-of select="$taxIncluded" />%
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

### Method 2:

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:param name="taxIncluded" select="20" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="InvoiceHeader">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Ex" as="element(Extrensic)?">
      <xsl:if test="not( Extrensic[@name='taxIncluded'])">
        <Extrensic name="taxIncluded" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$Ex" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Extrensic[@name='taxIncluded']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <percentage>
      <xsl:value-of select="$taxIncluded" />%
    </percentage>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Hi Sean, If I use the first approach it worked. But the xsl what we are using is pretty big(around 1000+ lines) and it affected some other part of code.When I analysed I found that, in <xsl:template match="@*|node()">  we had initially as @*| * , when I modified it to node() it started affecting some other part of the code. Could you please tell me is it possible to write the code without changing to @*|node() ? Thansks, Kitty

Comment: Just do `@*|*`. The difference between the pattern `*` and the pattern `node()` is that `node()` also matches processing instructions, comments and text.